# yarn run test --watch causing fail in jest + vite + react project

Tags: vite, babel-jest

Hi I've setup test enviroment with vite + react using thes configs:
https://gist.github.com/kapiljhajhria/fa3b49cb59e6c7c617247c79c73ca94f

but when I run the command:

`yarn run test --watch ./src/components/add-isin/add-isin.test.js`

it will run the test and after some seconds it will show this error and close:

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

thrown: [Error]

error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

is it a bug or I'm doing something wrong?